# The same string but false comparison

Tags: php, php-7

I have two strings. One from DB, second generated inside PHP.

var_dump of them:

```
string(67) "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.pl/pl/ubrania-tuniki?dir=asc&order=price"
string(63) "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.pl/pl/ubrania-tuniki?dir=asc&order=price"
```

How is it possible?

```
$a==$b
bool(false)
```

or

```
strcmp($a,$b)
int(-14)
```

Comment: 67 != 63. Looks like you have some funky characters in there

Comment: How can I check it? var_dump returns the same string inside quotas

Comment: Can you post the raw strings ? Save them to a temp file or read diretly from db?

Comment: Try running `unpack('C*', $string)` to unpack the string to bytes array. Maybe you'll notice differences.

Comment: @Wazelin Thank you. The problem was & => &amp;